# VueJS - Auto create a A-Z letters list from the data

Tags: vue.js

Is it possible to create a A-Z letters list ([like this](https://www.bls.gov/bls/topicsaz.htm)) from the data from a API and Vue to be able to determine if a property in a data contains a name that starts with what letter. If the data doesn't contain a specific letter name then remove/disable the href attribute from the letter anchor tag.

In the linked example, letters K, X and Z are missing coz they don't have the data

JSON

```
[
    {
        "id": 77,
        "link": "http://my-site/cosmoquotes/authors/anonymous/",
        "name": "Anonymous",
        "slug": "anonymous"
    },
    {
        "id": 72,
        "link": "http://my-site/authors/ferdinand-marcos/",
        "name": "Ferdinand Marcos",
        "slug": "ferdinand-marcos"
    },
    {
        "id": 75,
        "link": "http://my-site/authors/john-f-kennedy/",
        "name": "John F. Kennedy",
        "slug": "john-f-kennedy"
    },
    {
        "id": 67,
        "link": "http://my-site/authors/john-maxwell/",
        "name": "John Maxwell",
        "slug": "john-maxwell"
    }
]
```

Component

```
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      authorsRequest: {
        type: 'authors',
        params: {
          per_page: 100
        }
      },
    }
  },

  computed: {
    authors () {
      return this.$store.getters.requestedItems(this.authorsRequest)
    },
  },
  methods: {
    getAuthors() {
      return this.$store.dispatch('getItems', this.authorsRequest)
    },
  },
  created() {
    this.getAuthors()
  }
}
```

So as per the returned data, only the letters 'A', 'F' and 'J' should be clickable/displayed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to do it like this,
unfortunatly it needs the authors array and the conditionnal function to be outside of the Vue component because I couldn't find how to pass argument to computed values
But since I'm new to vue (didn't even finish reading the introduction) I'm sure there has to be a better solution

---

EDIT: found the way to have the function in the component with `methods`, I could then move the data in the component too

```js
let a = new Vue({
  el: "#selector",
  data: {
    authors: [{"id": 77,"link": "http://my-site/cosmoquotes/authors/anonymous/","name": "Anonymous","slug": "anonymous"},{"id": 72,"link": "http://my-site/authors/ferdinand-marcos/","name": "Ferdinand Marcos","slug": "ferdinand-marcos"},{"id": 75,"link": "http://my-site/authors/john-f-kennedy/","name": "John F. Kennedy","slug": "john-f-kennedy"},{"id": 67,"link": "http://my-site/authors/john-maxwell/","name": "John Maxwell","slug": "john-maxwell"}]
  },
  computed: {
    // there have to be a way to get this array without doing it like this but I don't know it ^^
    letters() {
      let letters = []
      for(let i = "A".charCodeAt(0); i <= "Z".charCodeAt(0); i++) {letters.push(String.fromCharCode([i]))}
      return letters
    }
  },
  methods: {
    // you may add a toUpperCase()/toLowerCase() if you're not sure of the capitalisation of you datas
    isALink(letter) {
      return this.authors.some(aut => aut.name.startsWith(letter))
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue"></script>

<div id="selector">
  <template v-for="letter in letters">
    <a v-if="isALink(letter)" :href="letter">{{ letter }}</a>
    <a v-else>{{ letter }}</a>
  </template>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can set the unique name as the id of dom. when you click to letter X, just get the first name start with X , and use getElementById to match the dom and scroll to the dom.